# Sql Directives error in visual cobol

Tags: sql, cobol

i am currently creating my project in cobol2 .. i am using a visual cobol of microfocus and was used a Ado.net for my database.. On the interface of openesql assistant i can insert values in my database table..
but on the form of my project on the button1 clicked i've got an error saying "NO SQL DIRECTIVES HAVE BEEN SET"

(here is my code

```
method-id button1_Click final private.
   procedure division using by value sender as object e as type System.EventArgs.

   EXEC SQL
    INSERT INTO NayreInventory  
    (ItemCode
    ,ItemDescription
    ,Quantity
    ,Price
     ) VALUES (
     :NayreInventory-ItemCode:NayreInventory-ItemCode-0001
    ,:NayreInventory-ItemDescription:Col-2-MEDICOL
    ,:NayreInventory-Quantity:NayreInventory-Quantity-5
    ,:NayreInventory-Price:NayreInventory-Price-150
     )
   END-EXEC. 

   invoke type MessageBox::Show("1 RECORD HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY ADDED", "RESULT")
   end method.
```

)
how to get rid on the error..
please help me .. i really nid ur help..

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a message number as well, like this?

"0149 No SQL directives have been set"

The description of that message is:

"An EXEC SQL statement has been encountered but no SQL directive has been specified. The processing of the statement varies depending on whether the directive SQL is set or not; either SQL or NOSQL must be explicitly specified.

See Also:
The SQL Compiler directive in the chapter Directives for Compiler in your Server Express User's Guide."

So it would look like you are missing a "compiler option" from your compile script.

This is from: http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx20books/emsynt.htm

To get the information I just googled your error message.

Comment: i've already google it but i really don't know and understand what its all mean..
please help me..
post some codes for a clearer views

Comment: Do you not have a Micro Focus manual? You need to set the compiler option/directive to either SQL or NOSQL, you need one or the other, you can't leave it off. I don't have a Micro Focus manual. It is perhaps whether the SQL statement, at "compile time", is deal with by a pre-processor or an inbuilt processor. SQL itself is not part of Cobol, so it has to be translated separately, depending on the compiler. Try "help" with the compiler, and look for something setting "options" or "directives".

Answer (score 1):

There are several [ways to specify Micro Focus COBOL compiler directives](http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx2011sp1/cycobc.htm#s016).  One way to specify your [SQL/NOSQL directive](http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx2011sp1/cyadir.htm#0147) is to embed the directive in your COBOL source, with the `$` in column 7, like so:

```
      $SET SQL
```

or, depending on your needs:

```
      $SET NOSQL
```

You can also use the [command line](http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx2011sp1/cyflag.htm):

```
cob -C SQL ...source file name and other arguments
```

Follow the links for more details.

Comment: I would also recommend move the SQL statements into a separate COBOL program.     You can also set the SQL or NOSQL directives at a project level and on a per-file basis.